# Странная работа оператора ввода из потока (">>") при чтении числа с точкой в int

Tags: c++

Допустим, есть переменная типа int, и пользователя приглашают ввести число, но он вводит, к примеру, 4.5. Считываем, выводим и получаем 4:

```
cin >> var1;
cout << var1; //Получаем 4
```

Всё вроде бы хорошо, компилятор отбрасывает дробную часть т.к. int, но попытаемся считать две переменные подряд:

```
cin >> var1 >> var2; //Пользователь вводит 4.5 и 5.5
cout << var1 << " " << var2; //Но получаем 4 и 0, второе число не считалось?
```

Второе число не считалось - в чем дело?
Теперь попробуем считать из потока следующим образом:

```
cin >> var1 >> var2 >> var2; //Пользователь вводит 4, 5.5, 6.5
cout << var1 << " " << var2; //Но получаем 4 и 0!
```

Очень странно! Теперь даже дробная часть не отбрасывается, число не считывается вовсе! Более того:

```
cin >> var1 >> var2 >> var2 >> var2; //Пользователь вводит 4, 5.5, 5, 5.
cout << var1 << " " << var2; //Но получаем опять 4 и 0!
```

То есть если в потоке хоть раз оказывается дробное число, оператор >> начинает странное себя вести при считывании в int. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Э, не. Потоковый ввод-вывод работает не так, как вы предполагаете.

Смотрите, что происходит.

Вначале, входной поток выглядит так:

```
^ '4' '.' '5' ' ' '5' '.' '5' '\n'
```

(крышкой обозначена текущая позиция в потоке). Теперь, ваш код читает переменную типа `int`. Что происходит? Из потока извлекаются символы до тех пор, пока (1) это цифры, (2) мы не переполнили значение типа `int`. Обратите внимание, ваш код **не** делает следующее: читает полностью число `4.5` до пробела, распознаёт в нём число типа `double` и округляет! Он просто читает до тех пор, пока считывается `int`. Для вашего случая, считается только `'4'`, так как точка не может быть частью записи `int`'а.

Итак, после считывания первого числа наш поток в таком состоянии:

```
'4' ^ '.' '5' ' ' '5' '.' '5' '\n'
```

Теперь любая попытка прочитать `int` не будет удачной, так как первым делом мы наткнёмся на символ `'.'`, с которого не может начинаться число.

Вы можете проверить, успешной ли была попытка ввода, при помощи конструкции

```
if (!cin) { /* упс, проблемы */ }
```

А вообще, если входной формат данных не гарантирован, я бы посоветовал делать по-другому: читайте всю строку ввода в `std::string` при помощи `std::getline`, и вытаскивайте из неё данные при помощи `stringstream`'а.